# Ajax calls not working

Tags: html, ajax

I'm having difficulty using my code:

```
<input id="button"  type="button" value="Load"/>
<div id="content"> </div>

<script src="js/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Using ajax: It seems to not run.

```
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'page.html', 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

page html contains `<span>Hello</span>`

Can anyone help me I don't know whats wrong I've tested with this and works properly:

```
<input type="text" onclick="$(this).hide();"/>
```

**NOTE** i have `<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you link the jquery.js library ?

Comment: why so ?? ajax and jquery are different i believe .

Comment: Ajax is just a concept . V can implement in two ways one is using jquery and the other is javascript . You used jquery so need to add jquery.js library file.

Comment: In which file u added those lines.

Comment: in the html file where the button is at

Comment: No, u have to add in ajax.js file . Because u coded your jquery in ajax.js file.

Comment: I just add this to ajax.js? <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> .  . the guide I'm following didn't do this yet he's ajax worked.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'page.html', 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: Your posting page "page.html" is placed where - inside js folder or outside of it. it is problem with ur linking of the file.URL must be url: '../page.html'

Comment: Don't mention it. I have mailed u check it out.

Answer (score 1):

first load jquery library at the top of your page

Comment: all of my code is shown here above. I tried testing the jquery its connected.

Comment: Nope the code above is the only thing in my ajax.js, Also i thought ready event is for on page reloads.

Comment: it's called once jquery is loaded fully.  in your JS file, add this:
$(function() {
 // your code.
});

Comment: I removed the external link and tried to do it. Still nothing once i clicked the load button. for the directories there all in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a dataType:

use the code below

```
<script>
$(function($) {
    $('#button').click(function() { 
        $.get('page.html',function(data)
        {
            $("#content").html(data);
        },"html")
    });
});
</script>
```

have fun:)